# Is hijrah from daar al-kufr ( the land of disbelief ) obligatory?

Tags: non-muslim-countries, obligation, hijra

I live and was born in a non-muslim country, i was also born in a religious family, however, my parents and grandparent came here in order to flee and escape war and the dreadful situations of their homecountry, and i later on found out that hijrah is fardh (obligatory) and my family doesn't know and i also saw a hadith of the prophet where he said something like, whoever settles with kuffaar,i have nothing to do with him. Please clarify, is it obligatory upon me to do hijrah? And if so am i sinning if my family don't support me and don't want to leave and i cannot leave alone.

Comment: This question has several issues one of them is that it includes many questions (see [on Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions?s=1|27.5177)) and the other is that the last question in your question title is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

**In the name of God, The Beneficent, The Merciful**

---

You’re allowed to stay in a non Muslim country, but this only if you’re able to practice the Islamic stuff such as praying, if you’re not able, then move to another Muslim country.

According to [*al-Islam.org*](https://www.al-islam.org/a-code-of-practice-for-muslims-in-the-west-ayatullah-sistani/migration-non-muslim-countries) you can migrate or visit any non Muslim land you wish. But when you visit, you have to spread Islam so that others too will convert to Islam. But it is dangerous to travel there, why? Because it leads to many evil things and you’ll probably do evil like them.

> Imam ar-Rida (a.s.) explained the prohibition of at-ta'arrub ba'd al-hijra as follows: "Since there is the danger that because of at-ta'arrub, he [the immigrant] might abandon [Islamic] knowledge, get involved with the ignorant people, and drift away"

The basic principle is that, is not permissible to settle in a non Muslim land because God Says( interpretation of the meaning):

> ”Indeed, those whom the angels take [in death] while wronging themselves - [the angels] will say, "In what [condition] were you?" They will say, "We were oppressed in the land." The angels will say, "Was not the earth of God spacious [enough] for you to emigrate therein?" For those, their refuge is Hell - and evil it is as a destination.” [**[The women, 4:97]**](https://quran.com/4)

That is in case, you’re not able to practice openly Islam in a non Muslim country. If you’re able to practice openly Islam, then there’s no sin upon you.